# Trying to find the highest grade of a student using Loops

Tags: c#, loops

So I am working on a homework right now, but am having trouble trying to figure out a working program
for my homework's objective. How it works is I input my class' names, their student IDs(numbers only), and their grade for a subject. The final should be to show the student's name, ID, and their highest grade in the subject.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int number = 0;
            int bestGrade = 0;
            int studentid = 0;

                for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter student name: ");
                    studentname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter student ID no.: ");
                    studentid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter student's FoP Prelim Grade: ");
                    grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (grade > bestGrade)
                    {
                          bestGrade = grade;
                    }
                }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}, Student ID: {1}, Has the highest grade of {3}", studentname, studentid, number);
        }
```

I apologize if my codes seem messy, and thank you in advance!

Comment: _Console.ReadLine_ returns a string. You don't need to convert a string to a string.

Comment: If you want to save all of the students with their id and grade. You can use a list and get the grade and name from the index of the list. If not, you can store the studentname, id and grade in the `if (number > largest)`

Comment: There are some suggestions already, but if I may ask, is it homework because you want to become a programmer, or as a side programming project? The reason for asking is: I am kind of fanatic at suggesting getting a feel for OOP as soon as possible. In this case, using `class`es or `tuple`s to store the input or max value

Comment: @Me.Name It's homework for my course, IT. I want to be more knowledgable about programming as a whole, because I plan to do some game development with my friends. I'm still in my 1st year of College and just started out this year, hence my lack of knowledge about the subject. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the easiest way, you can store the values in variables like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int bestGrade = 0;
    int bestStudentid = 0;
    string bestStudentname = "";

    for (var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter student name: ");
        var studentname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter student ID no.: ");
        var studentid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter student's FoP Prelim Grade: ");
        var grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (counter == 0)
        {
            bestGrade = grade;
        }
        else
        {
            if (grade > bestGrade)
            {
                bestGrade = grade;
                bestStudentid = studentid;
                bestStudentname = studentname;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{bestStudentname}, Student ID: {bestStudentid}, Has the highest grade of {bestGrade}");
}
```

If you want to store everything, you have to save them in a list or array and print it with the index of the largest grade.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to come up with something like this but I guess my lack in knowledge about programming made me unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to print out the Name, ID, and score for the student with the highest score, you can do that by storing all of the parameters in separate arrays. E.g., names in a string array, IDs and scores in int arrays. All of them will have the same array length, and thus you can iterate through the score array to find the largest score and then print the Name & ID using that index in your Console.WriteLine statement.

Comment: Ah, the [parallel arrays anti-pattern](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/). See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/350006/when-is-it-okay-to-use-parallel-arrays/350007 But why would the OP even need arrays here if the question is to just find the highest grade?